# Parse DQ rules from excel in AWS Deequ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-deequ

Does anyone have an example on how to parse Data Quality rules from an excel sheet in AWS DeeQu?

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe you use-case a bit more please?

In general, I would suggest to convert the data in Excel to a spark-supported format such as CSV or Parquet. From that point on, the data can be read with Spark and processed with deequ.